# Gallery with Firebase And Angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm doing an application With angular 6 and firebase, now there is a part where I need to show a gallery of images, these are in the storage of firebase. 
My question is: How can I get the url and other data as the name of these images, from angular? . Hope can help me. thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/learn/v4/content?persist_locale&locale=en_US there is a firebase example in one of the lectures.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you open your storage in firebase and click on a picture you get a side panel that shows you the picture and download url.
dd the download url to any of your image tags like so.
`<img src="https://firebase..."/>`

Also you can just add the images directly to your angular application assets folder instead. and pull it from there.

if you want to do that in more programmatic way please specify more detail and some snippet of code to actually be able to help more accurately.

Comment: Eso lo se amigo, pero necesito obtener las url desde mi aplicación de angular mediante algún servicio. Mediante angularfire2

Comment: [https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-file-uploads-to-firebase-storage/](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-file-uploads-to-firebase-storage/) Great tutorial how to save files and later retrieve them using angularfire2.
And I don't mean to be rude or anything but you would get a lot more help speaking english :D Had to translate your response.